# Почему я не могу активировать виртуальное окружение в PyCharm

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, virtualenv

Подскажите,  пожалуйста, столкнулся с проблемой, что при создании виртуального окружения в Pycharm, если открываю терминал через Windows PowerShell выдает ошибку:

```
Невозможно загрузить файл C:\Dev\backend_test_homework\venv\Scripts\activate.ps1, так как выполнение сценариев отключено в этой системе. Для получения дополнительных сведений см. about_Execut
ion_Policies по адресу http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
    + CategoryInfo          : Ошибка безопасности: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Если открываю терминал Bash, то также нет сокращения venv в начале строки. На команду "pip freeze" отражает пустую строку, на команду

```
$ virtualenv -p python3.8 venv
bash: virtualenv: command not found
```

Не могу понять причину, т.к. папка venv создана в директории, путь указан на python.exe в этой папке. В чем может быть причина?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как у вас и сказано, у вас в системе отключено выполнение сценариев. Так как у вас Windows, то сценарии выполняются с помощью PowerShell. Соответственно, вам нужно включить выполнение сценариев:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и после перезапустить PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

Не стал разбираться с `PowerShell`, поставил `Shell Path:` `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe`, вроде, работает.